# How to use CSS to add background color to dynamic user input matrix in R Shiny?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

The below reduced code example allows the user to input values into input matrixes. The first matrix `base_input` is static (with one input columns) and the next 2 input matrixes rendered are dynamic (with 2 input columns and expandable vertically). Data from `base_input` feeds into the 2 dynamic matrixes. I would like to add colour background to the sections of the input matrixes that are open for user input. I'm a complete CSS/HTML neophyte and managed to cobble the below CSS code in the `ui` section to correctly colour the `base_input` matrix, both when invoking the App and when the user makes an input change to `base_input`. Try and try but I am not able to do the same for the more dynamic input matrixes `var_1_input` and `var_2_input`, as shown in the image below. Any suggestions for how to do this?

[image]

Code:

```
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

matInputBase <- function(name) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(rep(20,2),2, 1,dimnames = list(c("A", "B"), NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

matInputVary <- function(name, x,y) {
  matrixInput(
    name,
    value = matrix(c(x, y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
    rows = list(extend = TRUE, names = FALSE),
    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 0, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  inlineCSS(list(".highlight" = "background-color: red;")),
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML("
      function applyHighlight() {
        $('#base_input td:nth-child(2)').addClass('highlight');
      }
      $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
        applyHighlight();  // Apply highlight when the app connects
      });
      $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
        if (event.name === 'base_input') {
          setTimeout(applyHighlight, 10);  
        }
      });
    "))
  ),
  sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max =10, value = 5),
  h5(strong("Variable (Y) over window (W):")),
  matInputBase("base_input"),
  uiOutput("Vectors")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({
    input$resetVectorBtn
    varNames <- c("A", "B")
      lapply(1:2, function(i) {
        list(
          h5(strong(paste("Adjust", varNames[i], "(Y) at time X:"))),
          matInputVary(paste0("var_", i, "_input"), input$periods, input$base_input[i, 1])
        )
      })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to resort to JavaScript. The matrix inputs have class `vue-input`, so you can simply use this CSS:

```css
.vue-input td:nth-child(2) { background-color: red; }
```

That is:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML(".vue-input td:nth-child(2) { background-color: red; }")),
  sliderInput("periods","Time window (W):", min = 1, max =10, value = 5),
  h5(strong("Variable (Y) over window (W):")),
  matInputBase("base_input"),
  uiOutput("Vectors")
)
```

Comment: Excellent, wow! In order to also add background colour to the first user input column of the `var_1_input` and `var_2_input` expandable input matrixes, I expanded your line of HTML as follows: `tags$style(HTML(".vue-input td:nth-child(1), .vue-input td:nth-child(2) { background-color: red; }"))`